# Value of texbox input is filled but returns empty/undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, input, textbox, floating-labels

I am new to javascript/typescript and I am trying to create a floating label for my text input widget. If the textbox contains a value I want to add a CSS 'active' class in order to add some styling to my textbox.

Below is part of my code for checking if the textbox contains a value. I do not understand why it fails.

```
//Structure texbox input widget
<div class="mx-textbox">
  <label class="control-label"> </label>
  <input class="form-control" value="Best"> 
</div>
```

```
//Part of my code for adding an 'active' class to my textbox div
init = () => {
        const floatContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.mx-textbox');
            
        floatContainers.forEach((element: HTMLInputElement) => {
            element.classList.add('floatLabel');
            const inputElement = element.querySelector('input');
            if (inputElement) {
                console.log(inputElement);
                console.log("value for " + inputElement.id + " is " + inputElement.value);
                if (inputElement.value) {
                    element.classList.add('active');
                }
              }  

            this.bindEvents(element);
        });
    };
```

When I check my console I can see the value's are found for my texboxes but if I try to check the value it seems to be empty?
[Console where you can see that my input items have a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG72l.png)

Can somebody explain me what to do or how to check it properly?

Comment: I think on if condition you should check that inputElement.value so it will only execute the block when inputElement has value.

Comment: Why are you assigning "Element" to "HTMLInputElement" in the forEach (element:HTMLInputElement)... With the HTML you pasted with the code it is working fine.

Comment: @MBB You are right, there is no need to do this. I removed the ': HTMLInputElement' part. Because I am using typescript there are some parts that need to be assigned but not for this element.

Comment: Your code works fine - https://playcode.io/767085

Comment: @MBB I debugged it and the value check seems te be executed too quickly. In the debugger the input value is empty. When the debugger is completed, the value seems to be there. Do you know how I can wait until the data is loaded into my textbox widget?